# Executing web requests inside of a loop only works on the first pass

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

I am taking a string message and breaking it up into chunks so that I can send it to an sms service (that consequently doesn't break it up for you). I after I do my work for break those messages up, I try loop through the resulting array and execute a web request. The problem is that it only works for the first message, and then hangs after that. After a short time, I get an error message saying "The connection was closed unexpectedly." This occurs at the second time it attempts GetResponse(); I've seen a few other posts on here that were simply saying to close and dispose the response and request streams. This isn't working for me at all. This is where my code is currently:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var oldMessage = GetFileString();
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Old message: {0}", oldMessage.Length));

    var newMessage = UrlPathEncodeString(oldMessage);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("New message: {0}", newMessage.Length));

    var brokenUp = SplitByLength(newMessage, 145).ToArray();
    for(var i = 0; i < brokenUp.Count(); i++)
    {
        brokenUp[i] = brokenUp[i].Insert(0, UrlPathEncodeString(string.Format("({0:D2} of {1:D2})", i + 1, brokenUp.Count())));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Appended length: {0}", brokenUp[i].Length));
    }

    System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 100;
    foreach (var block in brokenUp)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1500);
        SendSms((HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://172.20.5.214:90/method/sendsms"), block);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static void SendSms(HttpWebRequest request, string message)
{
    //build the request
    var url = "http://ipaddress/method/sendsms";
    //var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    var fields = "CellNumber={0}&Message={1}";
    fields = string.Format(fields, "16021234567", message);

    var fieldsBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fields);
    request.ContentLength = fieldsBytes.Length;
    var length = fieldsBytes.Length;

    using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        requestStream.Write(fieldsBytes, 0, length);

        using (var response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                responseStream.Close();
            }
        }
        requestStream.Close();
    }
}

public static byte[] ReadFully(Stream stream)
{
    var buffer = new byte[32768];
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        while (true)
        {
            int read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            if (read <= 0)
                return ms.ToArray();
            ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How long does manually trying that URL take to send the SMS? Longer than 1500ms?

Comment: And if I start and stop it 3 times really fast, I get 3 sms messages

Comment: Remove those calls to `...stream.Close()`.. the `using` statement does this for you as those streams close during their `Dispose` call. Once you've done that, give it another try. You could be pre-maturely closing the streams.

Comment: I just added those actually. I went ahead and removed them to try again. Same result

Comment: Just tried doing it async. Same result

Comment: My only suggestion then would be to slowly step through the code and see if the request and/or response are closed earlier than expected.

Comment: I'll try. But let me ask you this: if that were the case, why is it working on the first pass but not any of the subsequent passes? I almost feel like it's not getting closed/released at all

Comment: just as a side note you should always remove any personal information, when posting, that you hard coded such as the cell number in your code and IP Address with the port number that you communicate through.  Just use dummy info when posting it online as there is no relevance to having it out here on the net.

Comment: I usually do. The ip address is useless in this context.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I also noticed that even after leaving the using blocks, the request object connection property reads "Keep-Alive". I'm not sure if this affects anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've run into cases where `response.Close` appears to hang if you fail to download the entire contents of the response. Why this is, I don't know, but placing a call to `request.Abort` before calling `Close()` solves the problem. I wouldn't expect you to be seeing this problem, though, unless the response could potentially be many megabytes in size.

Also, failing to close the request stream before calling `GetResponse` might prevent all of the data from being sent. I would suggest calling `requestStream.Close` before making the request. But again, it seems odd that your code would work the first time but not on subsequent requests.

Your modified code, taking into account the changes I suggested, would be:

```
using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    requestStream.Write(fieldsBytes, 0, length);
}

using (var response = request.GetResponse())
{
    using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        // read the response here.
        request.Abort();
        responseStream.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I will give this a try when I get back to the office in the morning. Stay tuned :0 Thanks

Comment: well i gave this one a try but now I'm getting a different error. I'm getting a Gateway Timeout. Any ideas?

Comment: @Sinaesthetic: I can't say why the server would be returning a 504. It sounds to me as though the problem is on the server end rather than the client end.

Comment: Well it must have been an Authentication error that wasn't being returned. When I moved the context of the code into our actual service, everything worked fine! /sigh