# Webrequest inside loop only works on the first pass

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, httpwebrequest

I'm having the following code executed in a for each loop, it's executes for each item in a listbox. However, after the first executing the next (POST) requests do not seem to work for some reason. 
I debugged using fiddler but the status codes are just okay, also the tokens (RTVT & reloadToken) are fresh ones. 
I've found the following already-asked question right here on stackoverflow: [Executing web requests inside of a loop only works on the first pass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13261046/executing-web-requests-inside-of-a-loop-only-works-on-the-first-pass)
But I do not understand completely what fixed his error.

This is my current code in which is executed in the loop:

```
'Get reloadToken and RTVT
        Dim tokenRequest As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create("http://" & server & ".seafight.bigpoint.com/index.es?action=internalHome"), HttpWebRequest)
        tokenRequest.CookieContainer = cookieContainer
        tokenRequest.Method = "GET"
        tokenRequest.KeepAlive = True
        tokenRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111 Safari/537.36"

        Dim marketSourceCode As String = String.Empty
        Using sfreader As New StreamReader(tokenRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
            marketSourceCode = sfreader.ReadToEnd()
        End Using
        'WebBrowser1.DocumentText = marketSourceCode

        Dim reloadToken As String = RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(marketSourceCode, "(?<=reloadToken"" value="")(.*)(?="" />)").Groups(1).Value
        Dim RTVT As String = RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(marketSourceCode, "(?:RTVT.+value=')(?<RTVT>[^']+)").Groups("RTVT").Value

        Dim bidPostData As String = String.Format("reloadToken=" & reloadToken & "&setBid=true&ItemID=" & itemID & "&ItemType=" & itemType & "&currentSelecter=all&bidAmount=" & amount & "&RTVT=" & RTVT & "&ajaxAction=biddOnItem")

        Dim bidRequest As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create("http://" & server & ".seafight.bigpoint.com/ajax.es"), HttpWebRequest)
        bidRequest.CookieContainer = cookieContainer
        bidRequest.Method = "POST"
        bidRequest.KeepAlive = True
        bidRequest.ContentLength = bidPostData.Length
        bidRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        bidRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = True
        bidRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111 Safari/537.36"
        bidRequest.Referer = "http://" & server & ".seafight.bigpoint.com/index.es?action=internalMarketplace&subact=Elite"

        Dim encoding As New UTF8Encoding()
        Dim bidDataBytes As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(bidPostData)
        bidRequest.ContentLength = bidDataBytes.Length
        Dim stream As Stream = bidRequest.GetRequestStream()
        stream.Write(bidDataBytes, 0, bidDataBytes.Length)

        Dim webResp As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(bidRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

        Dim datastream As Stream = webResp.GetResponseStream()
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(datastream)

        Dim bidded As String = reader.ReadToEnd()

        WebBrowser1.DocumentText = bidded

        bidRequest.Abort()
        reader.Close()
        datastream.Close()
        webResp.Close()
        stream.Close()
```

Comment: No, this is Visual Basic, I have the same code in C# too, but with the same result: first POST request in the loop works but second and all after that do not.

Comment: when you say the second doesn't work. what exactly do you mean? i notice you have "WebBrowser1.DocumentText = bidded"

Comment: Well, I'm basically sending a POST request in a loop to the same uri, but each request with different data. However, the second post request (to that uri) is not 'accepted' or something. The POST request is, however, executed but not successfully/completely? I have know idea what it could be.
The WebBrowser you mentioned, is to show the result in a WebBrowser, just to see what happend.