# c# HttpWebRequest "POST" with Loop

Tags: c#, for-loop, stream, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I wanted do `POST` a `WebRequest` for a Browser game in a loop because the `POST` content contains a number. Now I have a frozen program.

Here is my Code:

```
String loginData = "login";

// Set Cookie 
CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

// Login

HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("URL");
req.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
req.Method = "POST";
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
byte[] loginDataBytes = encoding.GetBytes(loginData);
req.ContentLength = loginDataBytes.Length;
Stream stream = req.GetRequestStream();
stream.Write(loginDataBytes, 0, loginDataBytes.Length);
stream.Close();
HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

// Start the Loop

for (int i=1; i < 10; i++)
{

    String Friendly = "frday=" + i;

    req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("URL");
    req.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
    req.Method = "POST";
    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    byte[] Fr = encoding.GetBytes(Friendly);
    req.ContentLength = Fr.Length;

    Stream stream = req.GetRequestStream();
    stream.Write(Fr, 0, Fr.Length);
    stream.Close();

    Console.WriteLine("FriendlyNr: " + i);
}
```

The Ouput is:

> FriendlyNr: 1

And the Browsergame got only the one Post Content.

So the first run is working but the second rund did not work. The Programm freezes at

```
Stream stream = req.GetRequestStream();
```

I want to loop 10 times. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same `Stream` object - you need to use a new `HttpRequest` each time.  Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13261046/executing-web-requests-inside-of-a-loop-only-works-on-the-first-pass) to see a potential solution.  Make sure you are also closing the `Stream` object as well.

Additionally, putting the code in a using statement such as `using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())` will help make sure that the object is disposed of and collected appropriately.

Comment: Thank you <3 It helped me alot.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow!  If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted to help others find it in the future.  Thanks!